# XML Schema - Allow Invalid Dates

Tags: xml-parsing, biztalk

Hi I am using biztalk's FlatFile parser (using XML schema) to part a CSV file.  The CSV File sometimes contains invalid date - 1/1/1900.  Currently the schema validation for the flat file fails because of invalid date.  Is there any setting that I can use to allow the date to be used?

I dont want to read the date as string.  I might be forced to if there is no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change it to a [valid XML date time](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (e.g., 1900-01-00:00:00Z) using a custom pipeline component (see examples [here](http://biztalk.eliasen.dk/Pipelines.aspx)). Or you can just treat it as a string in your schema and deal with converting it later in a map, in an orchestration, or in a downstream system.

Here is a a C# snippet that you could put into a scripting functoid inside a BizTalk map to convert the string to an xs:dateTime, though you'll need to do some more work if you want to handle the potential for bad input data:

```
public string ConvertStringDateToDateTime(string param1)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(inputDate).ToString("s",System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

Also see [this blog post](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/behavior-of-biztalk-maps-scripting-functoid/) if you're looking to do that in multiple places in a single map.